# Rattle 5.1 ODBC connection issue

Tags: rattle

I've tried the ODBC connection in Rattle 5.1 many times with the same error.

Error in sqlTables(crs$odbc) : 
  first argument is not an open RODBC channel
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ORCL", believeNRows = TRUE) :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 28000, code 1005, message [Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-01005: null password given; logon denied
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=ORCL", believeNRows = TRUE) :
  ODBC connection failed

I've even hard-coded the password in OCBC.ini but it still doesn't work.

RODM_open_dbms_connection with the same DSN works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I downloaded R 3.4.3 on another laptop and the ODBC connection works. It's R 3.5.0 that it has problem with. Looks like Rattle 5.1.0 may not be compatible with R 3.5.0 yet.